# Type definition not a must for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

How does Haskell code work even without the Type declaration?

Comment: Type inference. (Questions asked without care get answers written without care.)

Comment: -1 http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_inference

Comment: Same reason as why `var` works in C#.

Comment: No. This question is vague, poorly written, and demonstrates absolutely no effort put forth by the questioner. 30 minutes reading just about any introduction to Haskell would provide a more thorough answer than the ones posted here so far, enough to either satisfy curiosity or inform a more meaningful question. **Laziness is for evaluation, not learning; please don't encourage bad questions.**

Comment: @camccann At a glance from the OP's SO history, she doesn't learns Haskell. Why should you downvote a question which is not naive at all for someone familiar to C and friends? Do you think a question "what is a pointer?" would be naive for someone familiar only to FP too? And why is it poorly written? The question pretty much explains what the OP wants to know. I don't see the point for a downvote. Many questions on SO can be answered by some googling, so that's not the point either. If you don't know the buzzword "type inference", it is not productive too search for an answer, either.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Many questions on SO are of poor quality and that's exactly the point. The *first item* on the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page says so and the `title` text on the downvote button gives "does not show any research effort" as the first reason. Questions that could be easily answered by reading the Wikipedia article on Haskell are not useful or appropriate and should be discouraged. And if the questioner *did* try to find out on their own, saying what they didn't understand will help get better answers. Learning is not a passive process.

Comment: Jeeeeez guys mellow out.  Maybe we could help the OP to write a better question instead of berating him and then arguing about it.

Comment: @luqui: Yes, you're right. I'm sorry, I'm being unnecessarily irritable today and not at all constructive. My apologies, to the OP and everyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming that you mean type signatures because if you remove type definitions like `type Foo = Bar` or `data X = Y`, the code will not work anymore (assuming the defined type is actually used of course).

Haskell code works without type signatures because the type of a variable/function is simply inferred by the compiler if you do not specify a signature. The algorithm used to make this inference is a variant of the [Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference#Hindley.E2.80.93Milner_type_inference_algorithm).

Answer (score 4):

Because very often, the type can be [inferred](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_basics) from the context. For example, the function `tail` has the type `[a] -> [a]` which say we go from a list to another list *of the same type*. When you pass a `String` to that function, it is known that another `String` is the result, so there is not really a need to explicitly say that. Thus, the type of `(tail "hello")` is known to be String (or `[Char]`, which is really the same).

Comment: -1 though you mention type inference, you then continue to elaborate on generics, which is not really what the question was about.

Comment: @Dan Maybe my example wasn't really good, did I really talk about generics? In my understanding, type inference means that you compose/chain functions, and each function transforms the types it operates on. So, when there is a `(+)` applied, whatever it is applied, whatever you apply it to must be an instance of `Num`. This fact is carried on, through the fabric you program is. Without explicitly stating it, it is clear for what kind of data your composition makes sense. Well, hopefully it's a total function, the type system does not check that.

Comment: On second look, inferring the type of `(tail "hello")` is a fairly good example for the question. On my first read I thought it focused more on the types of generic methods. Sorry for my hasty mistake.